# How to style the dropdown option select

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I want to style an option of a dropdown menu when it is hovered with a blue rectangle.

[image]

I am not sure how as I cant place a div inside an option... For example the div sqaureStyle does not exist here.

so is there a way in css to style an option

```
select option : hover{
   /* css style to create the sqaure? */
}



<select onchange="SetMonthsUpdatePayment('Custom','N/A')" id="drpTermList" class="form-control" asp-for="TermId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.PayTerms, "Value", "Text"))">
   <option value="-1"> <div id="squareStyle"> </div>Select Loan Term</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I use realized i can use ::before or ::after like this  select option::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: blue; /* Set your desired background color here */
}

Comment: Also looking into using Select2 jQuery Library